# How to implement Celebration Confetti animations on ionic 4 page load?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm creating ionic 4 app, now i want to add Confetti Animation on page load as well as page contain also display. for example suppose we win game and celebration animations happen on same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try out this one: 
[Fireworks](https://codepen.io/yshlin/pen/ylDEk)

```
// Create the explosion...
$box-shadow: ();
$box-shadow2: ();
@for $i from 0 through $particles {
  $box-shadow: $box-shadow,
               random($width)-$width / 2 + px
               random($height)-$height / 1.2 + px
               hsl(random(360), 100, 50);
  $box-shadow2: $box-shadow2, 0 0 #fff

...
```

Or that one:
[Confetti](https://codepen.io/fionnachan/pen/EvaqOB)

```
@for $i from 0 through 150 {
    $w: random(8);
    $l: random(100);
    .confetti-#{$i} 
    {
        width: #{$w}px;
        height: #{$w*0.4}px;
        background-color: nth($colors, random(3));
        top: -10%;
        left: unquote($l+"%");
        opacity: random() + 0.5;
        transform: rotate(#{random()*360}deg);
        animation: drop-#{$i} unquote(4+random()+"s") unquote(random()+"s") infinite;
    }
...
```

If you want to change the bubble size, there is the following class:

```
.pyro > .before, .pyro > .after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 5px;   // that one
    height: 5px;   // that one
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: $box-shadow2;
```

-> If you change the width or height the bubbles adapt to your chosen size.

Comment: sir, how to increase bubbles size.

Comment: Watch edit. You can change size by changing **width and height**